# I need one letter turned upside down in css

Tags: css, text

I know you can have text upside down but I am trying to have one single letter upside down is this possible?

Comment: Put it in its own container?

Answer (score 7):

You can use CSS transforms, basically rotation around the *x* axis. Wrap the letter in a `span` element and make it an inline block. Example (which works on modern browsers):

```
<style>
.upsidedown {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg); 
}
</style>
Here is a letter turned upside down: <span class="upsidedown">J</span>
```

However, CSS transforms tend to produce typographically poor results when applied to letters, especially for serif fonts. It is a also difficult to position rotated elements, e.g. if you would like to make it appear on text baseline (but this was not specified in the question).

Consider analyzing the original problem, trying to find a different approach. For example, if you need to turn a particular letter upside down, you might find a Unicode character that suits your needs

Comment: Good answer especially regarding comments at the end, wish every answer people posted was like this...

Answer (score 0):

Make a span with an upside down class, definining the upside down style, and apply it to a single letter.

```
<html>
...
Upside down <span class="upsidedown">U</span>.
...
</html>
```

There are many resources online that discuss how to define 180 degree rotations, for example

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/166266/Making-Text-Upside-down-using-CSS

Comment: Lots of resources, but none of them have worked well in my experience. Here's the one you linked to in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ZuKtB/ in Chrome the U goes over top of the text next to it.

Comment: You should add this observation to your question

Comment: Awesome! thank you that worked but know my kerning is all missed up in the word.  Like "David", I just want the A in David to be flipped but when I applied the class the spacing is squished together and idea on how to adjust. I know I can work with letter spacing